# SMSPrint causes error in FE code

Tags: acegen

I am using Mathematica 12.0, AceGen version 7.101. I have not detected this problem when I was using older versions of both, but I've had no need to use the `SMSPrint[]` command for quite some time, so I don't know if this problem is recent or not.
Using `SMSPrint[exp1,exp2,"Output" -> {"File", "test.out"}]` in the element code, causes the element .dll not to be generated in AceFem. This is the error I get:

> Compiler's messages: TestElement.c: In function 'SKR':
>   TestElement.c:4087:1: error: expected declaration or
>   statement at end of input  };  ^

By not using the option `"Output"->{"File", "test.out"}`, the `SMSPrint[exp1,exp2]` works fine, but I want to be able to print the results in a file, not inside the Mathematica notebook.

Another problem is the use of a new line `\n` in the expression inside the SMSPrint function. For some reason the element code is not even generated if new line is used. This is the error I get when I try to write the element code, using SMSWrite[]:

> SMC::Warning: Cannot split program
>   line.(Sigma=',(double)(v[1382]),(double)(v[1383]),(double)(v[1384]),(double)(v[1385]),(double)(v[1386]),(double)(v[1387]),(double)(v[1388]),(double)(v[1389]));
>   ).

For example, using the option `\t` inside the SMSPrint[] works fine.

Is there any fix to this, or am I doing something wrong? I have tested this on 2 different basic element codes, but have not tried using an older version of software.

Edit: I was able to recreate the error on an element code from AceShare found here http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si/MainLibraryV11/SE/7/SEMSS1ASHYANSP6DFiSVenant.html
By changing the "Mode" from "Optimal+" to "Debug", and inserting the SMSPrint[] function (that must include a newline \n) somewhere in the code, the same error ("Cannot split program line....") can be observed and the element is not generated.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE of your problem?

Comment: I have tried this also on the element code from AceShare. The code is found here http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si/MainLibraryV11/SE/7/SEMSS1ASHYANSP6DFiSVenant.html
By changing the "Mode" from "Optimal+" to "Debug", and inserting the SMSPrint[] function (that must include a newline \n) somewhere in the code, the same error ("Cannot split program line....") can be observed and the element is not generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) SMSPrint bug has already been corrected in version 7.103.

2) Special characters (e.g. \n) are not allowed as part of AceGen input. Safety reasons. Exception is SMSVerbatim statement. With SMSVerbatim you can insert an arbitrary C code sequence (see manual).